# Trying to alter this JSON search so that it only searches when a submit button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

New on here and a beginner at code.  I have this code I am using as a Karaoke search.  However, the JSON contains about 40 000 lines of info, and the search is set up to tigger on keyup, so it is very laggy sometimes.  I'm hoping someone can help me alter this code so that it only searches when a submit button is pressed...  Any ideas?  Greatly Appreciated

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('#search').keyup(function(){
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        var output = '<div class="row">';
        var count = 1;
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, val){
            if ((val.name.search(regex) != -1) ||     (val.location.search(regex) != -1)) {
              //output += '<div class="col-md-6 well">';

              //output += '<div class="col-md-7">';
              output += '' + val.name + ' - ';
              output += '' + val.location + '';
              output += '</div>';
              output += '</div>';
              output += '<div class="col-md-7"><a href="request.php?artist='+val.name+'&song='+val.location+'"><img class="img-responsive" src="send.png" /></a></div>';
              if(count%2 == 0){
                output += '</div><div class="row">'
              }
              count++;
            }
          });
          output += '</div>';
          $('#results').html(output);
        }); 
    });
  });
```

Comment: Read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: need to limit results no matter what you do. That's far too many results at one time for anyone to digest and for performance

Comment: I agree.. The issue is that when typing its finding things as you type.  I was hoping to speed things up by only showing results when you are done typing (and hit a button or enter key).

Answer (score 0):

The search logic should not be implemented on the client side. It would be painful for the browser to do that kind of iteration. Transfer your search logic in the backend. : )

if you're going to fixed that on front end, please add timeout/debounce during keyup

```
var delay = null;

$( el ).keyup( function () { 

     if ( delay ) clearTimeout( delay );

      var delay = setTimeout( function () { 

          // your search logic

      } );
 } );
```

Comment: I think people underestimate how beginner I am, lol.  I haven't a clue how to do backend stuff

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you placed your submit button within a form, give your form an ID.

```
<form id="search-form">
```

Change line

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
```

to

```
$('#search-form').on('submit', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
```